# Can there be more than one jQuery ready event on a page or in .js script?

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I noticed that the jQuery ready event and function are used only once in most of my javascript.  However, I was wandering if it is ok to use the ready event more than once. For example, is it ok to call functions in a ready event function call in my main html code, that then calls functions and events inside another ready event function call that is in my .js file?

Comment: It is ok to have multiple ready callbacks. As for your particular example, can you elaborate more and maybe provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is completely acceptable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do this
}):

// some other js code


$(document).ready(function() {
    // do something else
}):
```

In this case, when the dom is ready, code inside both (or as many `ready` as you have) will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

The ready event can be used more than once but you might run into issues with the order in which they run if your ready event handlers depend on each other.

Comment: I'm glad that you can use it more than once. In my application, it's a matter of modularizing the code. Some scripts will initialize, say, the "click" event on one set of buttons, other scripts for other buttons, while still more scripts will initialize, say, the "hover" event for a set of fields.

It's good to be able to put those into separate JS files based on whether a given page needs it, and know that those functions can run in their own separate "ready" block.