# Store value from cookie to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just getting started with JavaScript & jQuery and am figuring things out as I go, so apologies if this is a basic question. I have some simple code written to:

- Capture a value from a form
- Store it to a cookie
- Recall the value from the cookie and store it in a JS variable
- Print the JS variable

...but I can't get it to work. I can see that the cookie is being set properly, but for some reason, I can't retrieve it and write it to the variable. Here is my code, any help would be much appreciated!

```
<!-- CAPTURE A VALUE IN A SIMPLE FORM... -->
  <input id="txt" type="text" value="foo" />
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="1 - write cookie" />
  <input id="btntwo" type="button" value="2 - set cookie to variable" />
  <input id="btnthree" type="button" value="3 - print the cookie" />

<!-- WRITE THE VALUE TO THE COOKIE WHEN A USER CLICKS THE BTN... -->
  <script type="text/javascript">                                         
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").on("click", function () {
      $.cookie('myCookie', $("#txt").val(), { expires: 365 });
      });
    });                              
  </script> 

<!-- SET THE COOKIE VALUE TO A VARIABLE WHEN A USER CLICKS THE BTNTWO... -->
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btntwo").on("click", function () {
    var cookVal = $.cookie('myCookie')
  });
});
</script>     

<!-- PRINT THE COOKIE VALUE ON THE SCREEN WHEN A USER CLICKS THE BTNTHREE... -->
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnthree").on("click", function () {
    document.write(cookVal);     
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Multiple ready function is ok http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395843/can-there-be-more-than-one-jquery-ready-event-on-a-page-or-in-js-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cookVal` variable is local to the click-handler function, anything outside will not be able to access it.

Also, do not use `document.write` in event handlers. If the HTML is fully parsed (and the DOM ready), the document is closed. Calls to `document.write` after that will clear it and rewrite it.

Btw, you might join your separate scripts to a single one, that might make the code more readable.

```
<input id="txtin" type="text" value="foo" />
<button id="btn">write cookie</button>
<button id="btntwo">2 - set cookie to variable</button>
<button id="btnthree">3 - print the cookie</button>
<output id="txtout" />

<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function () {
  <!-- WRITE THE VALUE TO THE COOKIE WHEN A USER CLICKS THE BTN... -->
  $("#btn").on("click", function () {
    $.cookie('myCookie', $("#txtin").val(), { expires: 365 });
  });
  <!-- SET THE COOKIE VALUE TO A VARIABLE WHEN A USER CLICKS THE BTNTWO... -->
  var cookVal; // declared local to the whole onready function
  $("#btntwo").on("click", function () {
    cookVal = $.cookie('myCookie');
  });
  <!-- PRINT THE COOKIE VALUE ON THE SCREEN WHEN A USER CLICKS THE BTNTHREE... -->
  $("#btnthree").on("click", function () {
    $("#txtout").val(cookVal);     
  });
});
</script>
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/2L7Zb/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need multiple `$(document).ready` methods.

What gets outputted when you try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn").on("click", function () {
       $.cookie('myCookie', $("#txt").val(), { expires: 365 });
    });                              

    var cookVal = 'NOT SET';

    $("#btntwo").on("click", function () {
       cookVal = $.cookie('myCookie')
    });

    $("#btnthree").on("click", function () {
       document.write(cookVal);     
    });

});
```

If you look at your JavaScript for the `#btn` onclick, the syntax for saving the cookie is wrong. You're adding an extra `})` which will break the script. If you're ever unsure, use the Developer Tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox and look at your console. JavaScript errors are outputted there.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to put each of these in a separate `$(document).ready(function()` you can just put them all in one. Also the shorthand for this is:

```
$(function(){
............
});
```

Comment: Check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395843/can-there-be-more-than-one-jquery-ready-event-on-a-page-or-in-js-script

Comment: Read carefully, did not say that you could not have multiples only that you did not have to.

Comment: Your answer was more appropriate as a comment